# UIImage With Color & Centered Text

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uilabel, uigraphicscontext

I'm trying to add a convenience initialiser to the `UIImage` which will allow me to create an image with a given text centred in the middle, and given background color:

I've got the following code:

```
public convenience init?(color: UIColor, withText: String, withTextColor: UIColor, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)) {
    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = withText
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 40)
    label.textColor = withTextColor


    guard let cgImage = image?.cgImage else { return nil }
    self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
}
```

This creates the image with the correct background color - I'm not sure how to embed the `UILabel` in the middle of the image though.

EDIT

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Attributed strings know how [to draw themselves](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1529478-draw), so you don't need a label.  They also can [tell you how big they are](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1529154-boundingrect) or even wrap to fit an available width.  Here is playground that shows how to get an image from any attributed string:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

extension NSAttributedString {
  func asImage(size: CGSize = .init(width: .max, height: .max)) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: boundingRect(with: size, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin], context: nil)).image { context in
      self.draw(at: .zero)
    }
  }
}

let attributedString = NSAttributedString.init(string: "testing", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white])
let image = attributedString.asImage()
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = imageView
```

Comment: thanks - do you know how I could combine this with the code I added in the question which also sets a background color for the image?

Comment: Just add a background color to the string attributes.  `NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: UIColor.blue`

Comment: thanks - managed to do it but the size of the text ("+") in this case doesn't seem right and it's quite blurry too - what I want to achieve is basically a small + in the middle of the circle - so I'd like to be able to control the size of the text and size of the image separately. I added how it looks as an edit to the question.

Comment: You should be using my code, not the code you provided in the question.  UIGraphicsImageRenderer takes the current screen scale into account while the older UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions does not, so you are rendering at the wrong resolution which causes the blurry image.

Comment: I am using your code - I copy-pasted the extension and am using it as you suggested but I'm still getting the blurry image

Answer (score 0):

Here is the convenience initialiser drawing white text in the centre of a red image:

```
convenience init?(letters: String) {
    let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    style.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    let sizeOfImage = CGSize(width: 120, height: 120)
    let font = UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 50)!
    let imageText = NSAttributedString(string: letters, attributes: [.font: font, .foregroundColor: UIColor.white, .paragraphStyle: style])
    let textHight = font.lineHeight
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: sizeOfImage)
    let image = renderer.image { context in
        UIColor.red.setFill()
        context.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: sizeOfImage))
        imageText.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: (sizeOfImage.height - textHight) / 2), size: sizeOfImage))
            }
    self.init(cgImage: image.cgImage!)
        }
```